# Accessing server with authentication using libcurl

Tags: c, server, libcurl

I am trying to access a company internal webpage that requires authentication using libcurl. When the code is run, it says "401 UNAUTHORIZED". I am providing the login credentials via curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "usr:pwd"), but still get the above message.

I read on this and found that 401 means it requires a SERVER authentication. However, I do not receive any available authentication schemes. My winhttp config settings are on 'Auto-detect'.

```
int wmain()
{
    std::string content;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "company internal URL");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "usr:pwd");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
        CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
    std::cout << content;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I am very new to using libcurl and have limited working experience with C/C++. Your help is appreciated to identify the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);`

Also of course `"usr:pwd"`should be replaced, but I assume you did that.

Example below

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH.html

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  CURLcode ret;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");
  /* allow whatever auth the server speaks */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "james:bond");
  ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
```